# GPA data across majors

Tags: reference-request, gpa, major

I read an article recently showing research data of the average graduating GPAs for various majors. It was a discussion piece about whether or not humanities majors were more likely to have higher GPAs given the increased opportunity for professors to be subjective in grading. (Very interesting piece.)

However, I would like to know more than just the average of GPAs. For example, the percentile you would be in if you had *x* GPA in *y* major.

Does such data exist?

Comment: My impression is that this last statistic could vary widely over different schools.

Comment: Since it's a very interesting piece, could you please put a reference to it? ;-)

Comment: Note that you can't necessarily directly compare grading standards across majors by looking at GPA, because students self-select into majors based partially on things like how hard they want to work in college.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This data is available for the United States as part of the NCES [Baccalaureate and Beyond Longitudinal Study](https://nces.ed.gov/surveys/b&b/about.asp) (B&B). You can create a free account, then run some basic data analysis on their data using their [PowerStats](https://nces.ed.gov/datalab/powerstats/default.aspx) tool. (You could definitely use it to compute what "percentile would you be in if you had x GPA in y major" - I just tried it for myself. I was apparently a 95.1st percentile student as an undergrad :))

Here's a table I just made there of 10th, 25th, 50th, 75th, and 90th percentile GPA by major:

[image: GPA by major]